# mdframed package conflicting with \bgroup, \egroup

Tags: environments

I'm using XeLaTeX because of language problem.

The following code has no problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{mynote}{\footnote\bgroup}{\egroup}
\begin{document}
Hello\begin{mynote} world\end{mynote}.
\end{document}
```

However, the following code gives an error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{mynote}{\footnote\bgroup}{\egroup}
\begin{document}
Hello\begin{mynote} world\end{mynote}.
\end{document}
```

What is the reason for the error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `\footnote`, in LaTeX, can't be followed by `\bgroup` in order to build its argument. If it appears to work is just by chance and it will be typeset incorrectly anyway.

Comment: The reason why this fails with `mdframed` is because the package adds code to `\begin` and `\end`. But trust me: your `mynote` environment ***doesn't*** work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `environ` you can define an environment which collects the body for later use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,environ}
\newsavebox\NBox
\NewEnviron{mynote}{\footnote{\BODY}}

\begin{document}
Hello\begin{mynote} world\end{mynote}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution resolved the problem. However, I still wonder why the second code have not worked...